# In AWS Cognito, how to re-send verification code after email update (not after sign up)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on AWS Cognito with PHP Symfony (but I don't think the fact that I am with Symfony is relevant to the question).

This topic is not related to the validation after sign up, for which there is the [ResendConfirmationCode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ResendConfirmationCode.html) request.

In my case, when a user updates their email, which is done with [updateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateUserAttributes.html), on the email attribute, they receive a code (similarly to the sign up process). This code is then used to verify the email with [VerifyUserAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyUserAttribute.html). If, for some reason, they didn't receive the email, how can I resend this email ?

I tried with ResendConfirmationCode, but the code is not valid, and that's not surprising since the documentation says that this request is for confirmation of registration (so not for just changing your contact details).

I tried to reset the email address with updateUserAttributes, but since the address doesn't change, it doesn't resend the email either.

Does anyone a solution to this?

Thanks